# htaccess url rewrite but executes the same page

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have an url like

```
http://example.com/folder1/folder2/admin_login.php
```

the above is active page. but i want to show the below url instead of above but functioning the same page.

```
http://example.com/folder1/folder2/login
```

So the question is display url-2 in browser but exeuctes url-1

i have tried this code in htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2/admin_login.php$  http://example.com/folder1/folder2/login [NC,L]
```

When i put url-1 in browser address bar. it will convert into the url-2 but shows `Page Not Found`

Comment: is your last sentence correct? You put url-***1*** in browser? Why you do that?

Comment: @Sharky i mean to say browser address bar ok i had correct it

Comment: no there was no problem in browser/address bar, my comment was about if you put url-***1*** or url-***2*** in address bar. What you type in address bar? Url-***1*** or Url-***2***? If you type Url-***1***, then why?

Comment: no i want to execute the `admin_login.php` which have login page but address bar should show `/admin` instead of `admin_login.php` so that the file name can be hide

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have it turned around. You want the second url to be in the address bar. That means you have to link to that url. When a request with that url comes to the server, the server has to internally translate that url to a working url. Besides that, you should not have the full url as a rewrite target, because this causes the rule to function as a redirect instead of an internal rewrite.

The following rule should do the trick:

```
RewriteRule ^folder1/folder2/login/?$ /folder1/folder2/admin_login.php [L]
```

Comment: thanks its working. i am new in using htaccess. would please provide me some urls(sites) for learning better. how it can be use.?

Comment: what is difference between `[NC, L]` and `[L]`

Comment: Read the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html). Googling "mod_rewrite example" should bring up lists upon lists of examples for common problems. The `NC` flag ignores case in the url. With the flag, `example.com/folDER1/FoLdEr2/LOGIN` would match too, while without the flag it is more strict. I find there is usually no reason to use it.